# windows DLL issues

Tags: windows, vba, dll

I'm having problems with an Excel VBA application that uses a C DLL. The DLL is always stored in the directory above the Spreadsheet and it's methods are called from within VBA using;

```
#If Win64 Then
   Public Declare PtrSafe Function <function name> Lib "..\<dllname>" () As Long
#else
   Declare Function <function name> Lib "..\<dllname>" () As Long
#end if
```

You can wrap these two files and their directory structure in a zip file, move it around windows installations (different versions and 32- or 64-bit) and it works fine except with one computer and we haven't a clue why. All we get is an error that the program can't find the dll at ..\ from the VBA method that called the dll method. Installing MFC100.dll solved a previous runtime error 53 problem which got us to where we are.

If you've any advice on how to solve this, or ideas on what to try, I would be very grateful,
James

Comment: I think that code will only work if the current directory is the directory containing the spreadsheet.  That might not be the case, for example, if Excel was already open when the spreadsheet was opened.  Perhaps this is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

VBA will tend to complain that it "can't find" a DLL if actually the issue is one of the DLL's dependencies is missing. I suspect that's the problem. Try (re-)installing the [Visual C++ libraries](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5555). Or, open the offending DLL in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (or a similar tool) to find out exactly what it wants.

Comment: We've installed the MS VC++ 2012 DLL's and checked the dependencies flagged up by Dependency Walker, they're all as you would expect. MFC100.DLL,MSVCR100.DLL,KERNEL32.DLL,USER32.DLL,GDI32.DLL,ADVAPI32.DLL,SHELL32.DLL,OLEAUT32.DLL,MSVCP100.DLL. I'm wondering if this is a registry problem?

Comment: @James Possibly. Per @HarryJohnston's comment up above, it could be a path problem. Try issuing this statement: `ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path` just before loading the DLL. Also did you try @ElectricLlama's suggestion? Procmon will show you where Excel looks for the DLL file or what it looks for next when it finds it.

Answer (score 2):

While your downloading dependency walker, download [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see where your VBA app is actually looking at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that we'd not installed the 64-bit version of the VS C++ redistributable, only the 32-bit version. Once this was installed, everything worked fine.